# Python Tkinter - How to use a font which is not installed on a different pc while running the EXE program on it?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a program in Python using TKINTER GUI and I`m using a special font i have downloaded.
I gave all elements the font family definition - something like this :

`label000.config(font=('Retro Team', 74), fg='black')`

This application is being used by several users and they don`t have this font installed on their PC.

is there any way not asking them to install it manually before execution?

Thanks !

Comment: You can try `pyglet.font.add_file()` from `pyglet` module.  But make sure you have the right to distribute the font.

Comment: The problem is that `pyglet` is an external module, so the other PC might doesn't have that as well. But tkinter has a huge amount of fonts, there must be one that will satisfy you?

Comment: @Eladtopaz I don't think that is what acw1668 meant. I don't think the computers OP distributes to even have Python. OP should add `pyglet` to their program, then again convert to `.exe` and distribute again (or maybe they have some code that can automatically update itself). and as you said there are a lot of fonts and one must satisfy the OP, well that one font is this one

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys !
pyglet.font.add_file did the trick.
i have located the font file in our network and mapped Pyglet to it.

Thanks